# (Discord.py rewrite) How do i make it so instead of just minutes, i can use minutes and hours in an arg?

Tags: discord, discord.py

I have a discord.py rewrite bot with a mute command and i'm not sure how to make it so that instead of just doing the number of minutes, i can split it into hours and minutes, for example, right now it's `!mute @user 90` and i'd want it to be `!mute @user 1h30m`, how would i achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

The best way to this is regular expressions.

```
import re

REGEX = "([0-9]+)(d|h|m|s)"
DICT = {"d": 86400, "h": 3600, "m": 60, "s": 1}
matches = re.findall(REGEX, TIME_STRING))
seconds = 0
for k, v in matches:
  seconds += DICT[v] * int(k)
```